# Finding elements in $S_{3}$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Question: In $S_{3}$, find elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\left | \alpha \right |=2,\left | \beta \right |=2$ and $\left | \alpha 
> \beta \right |=3$

I note that the permutation in $S_{3}$ is a product of transpositions.

Useful hints would be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are three elements of order two in $S_3$. If you pick $\alpha=\beta$ it does not work. If you pick $\alpha\ne \beta$ it does.

Answer (score 6):

Take two different transpositions, for example $\alpha=(1\ 2)$ and $\beta=(1\ 3)$.

Comment: I see it. Thanks. I made it more complicated that is.